# Formatting C# two dimensional array to Javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, arrays, list

Is there a simpler way of converting a two dimensional array in C#, such as [[1, 2, 3],[4, 5, 6]] into a string that says "[[1, 2, 3],[4, 5, 6]]", other than incrementing through each value and adding in the syntax manually?

I would like to use the array as an argument in my webView.ExecuteJavascript() method, which takes the method name string as an argument. Ideally, in C#, it would look like

```
webView.ExecuteJavascript("updateValues([[1, 2, 3],[4, 5, 6]])")
```

The updateValues function in javascript looks like this

```
updateValues(newvalues) {
oldvalues = newvalues
}
```

Would there be an easier way to do this? Right now, the results are stored in a list of double arrays (List), and calling .ToArray().ToString(), in a form such as this:

```
webView.ExecuteJavascript("updateValues(" + gaugeCol.ToArray().ToString() + ")");
```

only gives me the variable type and not the actual values.

Thanks

Comment: if you are asking about a recommendation for a library then this is out of scope for this site. as you know, there is no other way than going through each element and converting them to strings.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [JavaScriptSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
var arr = new[] { new[] { 1, 2, 3 }, new[] { 4, 5, 6 } };
string json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(arr);
```

or [Json.Net](https://json.codeplex.com/)

```
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(arr);
```

That way, you can convert almost any kind of object to [json](http://json.org/), not only arrays...

Answer (score 1):

You can use an expression like this to turn the list of arrays into the Javascript syntax:

```
"[" + String.Join(",", gaugeCol.Select(g =>
  "[" + String.Join(",", Array.ConvertAll(g, Convert.ToString)) + "]"
)) + "]"
```

Comment: I am curious why it was down-voted. What, this code does not produce the desired result?

Comment: @akonsu: I'm curious too. The code is tested, and does produce exactly the desired result.